# Grails 3: Bulk insert performance issue

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, bulkinsert

**Grails Version: 3.3.2**

I have 100k records I am loading from a CSV file and trying to do a bulk save.  The issue I am having is that the bulk save is performing worse than a non-bulk save.

All the online searches I did basically use the same methods as this site which I referenced
http://krixisolutions.com/bulk-insert-grails-gorm/

I tried all 3 solutions on the page, here is an example of one of them:

```
def saveFsRawData(List<FactFsRawData> rawData) {
    int startTime = DateTime.newInstance().secondOfDay;
    println("Start Save");

    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

    rawData.eachWithIndex{ FactFsRawData entry, int i ->
        session.save(entry);

        if(i % 1000 == 0) {
            session.flush();
            session.clear();
        }
    }
    tx.commit();
    session.close();

    println("End Save - "+ (DateTime.newInstance().secondOfDay - startTime));
}
```

I have tried various bulk sizes from 100 to 5k (using 1k in the example).  All of them average around 80 seconds.

If I remove the batch processing completely then I get an average of 65 seconds.

I am unsure of what the issue is or where I am going wrong.  Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, try for more bulk insert records (e.g. 50K, 100K) then you absolutely get the difference.

Comment: @PrakashBhavnath I'm doing 100k records with 1k batches between session flushes.  So your saying I should be doing 50k records between flushes?  That seems like alot but I'll try